# radiobutton: how do i retrieve data from db

Tags: c#, ms-access

Access 2003 db

```
Field Name          Data Type  
CriminalOffence     Text
```

VS 2010 C#

Using a groupbox, I can store data from radiobutton into my db. I have databinded both  groupbox and radiobuttons to my db. When I use my nativgation buttons I see the data that has been stored where the groupbox text is. So the problem is I don't know how to properly retrieve data for the radiobutton. Retrieving data from textbox and combox is showing as it should be. Also when I want to insert new data the radiobutton does not get cleared. So...

I have two radiobuttons named, 1) rBYes 2) rBNo

I have the following method for inserting record...

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table1
                                    (ID, AgeGroup, Gender, CriminalOffence)   
                              VALUES(@txtID, @AcBAG, @cBGender, @CriminalOffence)", myCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", cBAG.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cBGender.Text);

        string str = "";
        if (rBYes.Checked)
        {
            str = "Yes";
        }
        if (rBNo.Checked)
        {
            str = "No";
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriminalOffence", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =   
        str;
    }
```

And a method for creating a new record

```
 private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtID.Text = "";
        cBAG.Text = "";
        cBGender.Text = "";
        rBYes.Text = "";
        rBNo.Text = "";
    }
```

An example of navigation button..

```
    private void btnNextRec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.table1BindingSource.MoveNext();
    }
```

ConnectionString...

```
    myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\..
    \Database1.mdb");
```

Please can someone help me here, thanks in advance

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. It saves to the database, but how does it mess up the rest of the current data?

Comment: @Melanie - Do you have alternative way of doing this? From your response I think you are saying it should work?

Comment: You have wrong parameter names. `@textID` becomes `@ID` for some reason, and so on. Also, are you sure you have to `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter names must match the parameters in the SQL insert statement.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table1
                                        (ID, AgeGroup, Gender, CriminalOffence)   
                                  VALUES(@ID, @AgeGroup, @Gender, @CriminalOffence)", myCon);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", cbAG.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cbGender.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CriminalOffence", ((rBYes.Checked)? "Yes":"No"));

  myCon.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  myCon.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: I am able to save values from radio button in ms access but I am unable to retrieve data from db. I have used groupbox and when I use navigation buttons I am able to see text value on the group. I would I would like to retrieve value in the radiobutton, where the user clicks the dot for inserting value. Perhaps I may not be explaining well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: My navigation buttons are tied to data binding. So when you goto next record previous record last and first record, referring to buttons. Data in textboxes and combo box are navigated with the those buttons. With me so far? What I am trying to say is that it is not happening with radio buttons (the green dots). I have bind those radio buttons as well without success. I am not actually want to use the group box and I am only using it for test purpose.